# const function and references

Tags: c++, templates, constants

If you notice in the following functions they both have the same for loop that searches for a integer location. Pop() compiles but I get an error for top() having to do with the const qualifiers. The heap class inherits from eecs281heap which stores a functor Comp compare where Comp is the typename. The instructor told us the only way to access the functor is through this->() so i'm just lookin for some guidance here. Thanks

error: passing ‘const larger’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool larger::operator()(int, int)’ discards qualifiers

This happens after running the following in int main. Through testing I already know the constructor works properly.

```
vector <int> data={10,2,13};
poorman_heap<int,larger> y(data.begin(),data.end());

template<typename TYPE, typename COMP>
void poorman_heap<TYPE, COMP>::pop() {
    int location=0;
    for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++){
        if(this->compare(data.at(i),data.at(location))){
            location=i;
        }
    }
    data.erase(data.begin()+location);
    return;
}

template<typename TYPE, typename COMP>
const TYPE& poorman_heap<TYPE, COMP>::top() const {
    int location=0;
    for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++){
        if(this->compare(data.at(i),data.at(location))){
            location=i;
        }
    }
    return data.at(location); 
}
```

P.S. greater is

```
struct greater{
    bool operator()(int x,int y){
        return x>y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that `compare` is not `const`?

Comment: i thought that was the case but i'm not allowed to change any of the class compilations so when i pass in the greater functor for compare, i don't know how to access it with top()

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. Are you saying `this->compare` is a `greater` instance? If so, your code is broken because it assumes `TYPE` is `int`. But you can create a local `greater` instance on the fly, that allows you to call non-const methods on it.

Comment: my constructor initializes a functor accessed through this->compare which i pass greater than to.  When using it in other methods, it works properly and sorts appropiately.  Keep in mind, any functor can be passed into the class to store but in this case i chose greater. I'm just having trouble accessing this functor in the top() class if that makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the call operator of `greater` a `const` operator:

```
struct greater
{
    bool operator()(int x,int y) const
    {
        return x>y;
    }
}
```

The same applies to whatever `this->compare` resolves to. It needs to be `const`.

It doesn't make much sense for a comparator to be non-const.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that the `compare` member has `operator()` declared as a non-`const` function. Since it sounds like you don't have the ability to change that, you might be able to get the behavior that you want by declaring it as a `mutable` member in `poorman_heap`.

The `mutable` keyword lets you distinguish between an object being "physically `const`" (meaning the actual bytes don't change and being "logically `const`" (meaning the bytes might change but the value of the object isn't different in a fundamental sense). Basically it means that something "doesn't count" for the purposes of `const`-ness. The classic example in my mind is lazy initialization - you want to declare the `get_value()` function on a class `const`, but you also don't want to waste time computing the value if no one uses it, so you declare the value `mutable` and now you're allowed to calculate it and assign to it inside `get_value()` even though it is a `const` member function.